# Парсинг selenium+tor

Tags: selenium, proxy, vpn, tor

Вообщем настроил парсер через тор selenium, но вылезает капча на сайте, тогда я попробовал бесплатные прокси листы, тоже самое. Потом скачал vpn и все работает. Объясните почему?

Comment: По-моему, сервера могут определять, что ip к ним приходит из tor и уже из-за этого могут капчу запрашивать, а бесплатные прокси могли быть замечены в досе (или у сервера есть список ip из бесплатных и для них проверка выполняется), а ip с того vpn, похоже, не был замечен в хулиганствах :)

Comment: Тогда по логике если буду парсить с бесплатных vpn то и их адреса по итогу забанят навсегда?

Comment: Такое возможно. Но сайты редко банят ip если те их не досят, тем более, если вы через selenium будете работать, тогда сайту будет очень сложно понять что это бот, а не человек (например, рандомная задержка между запросами уже уменьшит вариант блокировки, ведь не будет доса и предопределенности -- запросы от одного ip ровно 1 раз в секунду могут вызывать подозрения)

Comment: По-моему вы это зря делаете, вероятно этот сайт парсить запрещено.